# How to use a lambda function with an if-else statement in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, messagebox

Hi I'm a beginner in Python and tkinter and I need to use a Button that show me the value in a dictionary according to a key introduced by an user through an Entry. If the introduced key is in the dictionary the value should be shown in a Disabled Entry for the description of  the key, and if it is not in the dictionary it should show a message box asking for a different key. I'm using an if-else lambda function in the command of the button but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why.

I'll put the code I'm using below.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root=Tk()

dictio={1:"one", 2:"two"}

test=False
textEntry = StringVar()
def show_description(key, dict, text):
    if key in dict.keys():
        textEntry.set(text)
    else:
        test=True

code_entry = Entry(root)
code_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')
description_entry = Entry(root, state="disabled", textvariable = textEntry)
description_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

show_button = Button(root, text="Mostrar descripción", command=lambda test:show_description(int(code_entry.get()),
                                                                                dictio,
                                                                                dictio[int(code_entry.get())]) if (test==False) else messagebox.showinfo("Info", "The number is not in the database"))


show_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just define a normal python function. It will make your code more readable/debuggable.

Comment: @TheLizzard but with a normal function I can't assign the arguments in the button command, that's why I'm using a lambda.

Comment: Sure you can. Define `def foo(test): ...`, then use `Button(root, text="...", command=foo)`.

Comment: Your code will be much easier to write, read, and manage if you create a proper function rather than cramming code into a complex lambda.

Comment: The callback of `command` option of a button should take no argument, so your lambda (with `test` argument) should cause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `command` argument requires a function with no positional arguments, so using `lambda x: <do-something>` will raise an error. In this case none of the arguments need to be passed during the callback and so you should simplify things to

```
def show_description():
    key = int(code_entry.get())
    if key in dictio:
        textEntry.set(dictio[key])
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "The number is not in the database")

show_button = Button(root, text="Mostrar descripción", command=show_description)
```

Also, doing this

```
dictio[int(code_entry.get())]
```

the way you did could have raised a `KeyError` after fixing the lambda having no arguments.

Comment: Thank! Now I see, I was just over-complicating the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root=Tk()

dictio={1:"one", 2:"two"}

test=False
textEntry = StringVar() 
display=StringVar()
def show_description():
    print(display.get()) #==get the value of the stringvat
    x=int(display.get()) #==convert the value to integer
    if dictio.get(x)==None:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "The number is not in the database")
    else:
        textEntry.set(dictio.get(x)) #==get the value of the key from dictio dictionary and set it for description_entry
code_entry = Entry(root,textvariable=display)
display.set("") #==set value as nothing
code_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')
description_entry = Entry(root, state="disabled", textvariable = textEntry)
description_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

show_button = Button(root, text="Mostrar descripción", command=show_description)


show_button.grid(row=0, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: OP's code had a `messagebox.showinfo(...)`. Where did it go? Also do you mind adding a bit of explanation to what you changed/how it works?

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged here. This answer will be much more useful if you describe the changes you made to the code.